# check if you have the right to merge on multiple projects of a bitbucket git repo

Tags: bitbucket

I need to check if I have the right to merge PR on a wide range of bitbucket project.(without merging anything of course)
Any command line who can check it ? or way of listing all my right for all the repo?

Comment: I feel like this should not be tagged [tag:git]. Git has no knowledge of what a "privilege" is, so at most, you'll get error messages trying to push somewhere you are not allowed to push. Check out these [SQL queries](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/list-all-permissions-and-users-of-projects-and-repositories-in-bitbucket-972333742.html) to get all permissions and users of projects and repos. You can probably parse it and determine where you have rights

Comment: I remove the tag